# How To Make Custom Progress Bar with certain percentage as per data

Tags: ios, progress-bar, percentage, swift4.2

How To Add Custom Progress Bar with certain percentage which will change according to data values.  I want animation as well so that when i will come on that screen percentage increasing must be shown.

[image: I want this type of progress view]

Comment: Take a search for `swift custom progress bar` ... you'll find lots and lots of examples to get you on your way.

Comment: Already did the same but not able to do the same

Comment: OK - well you need to show what you've tried, and explain what you're having trouble with. Please review [ask].